# How to prevent web.config reverting during publish to azure from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, web-config, publishing

When I publish my .net core app to azure, the web.config seems to revert to something else and I can't figure out why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" />
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="300000000" maxUrl="102410" maxQueryString="204810" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <applicationInitialization>
        <add initializationPage="/" />
    </applicationInitialization>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But what arrives on the server is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.UI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The security and appinitialization sections completely disappear.    What's going on here?

Comment: Looks wired to me! Could you deploy this by creating another web application?

Comment: Same in a blank application too...it really is odd